# Using SQL to determine word count stats of a text field

Tags: mysql, sql, text-processing, word-count

I've recently been working on some database search functionality and wanted to get some information like the average words per document (e.g. text field in the database). The only thing I have found so far (without processing in language of choice outside the DB) is:

```
SELECT AVG(LENGTH(content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(content, ' ', '')) + 1)
FROM documents
```

This seems to work* but do you have other suggestions? I'm currently using MySQL 4 (hope to move to version 5 for this app soon), but am also interested in general solutions.

Thanks!

* I can imagine that this is a pretty rough way to determine this as it does not account for HTML in the content and the like as well. That's OK for this particular project but again are there better ways?

**Update:** To define what I mean by "better": either more accurate, performs more efficiently, or is more "correct" (easy to maintain, good practice, etc). For the content I have available, the query above is fast enough and is accurate for this project, but I may need something similar in the future (so I asked).

Comment: This helped me solve my problem, but I discovered that some of my fields have trailing spaces, so I used LENGTH(TRIM(content)) instead of LENGTH(content).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The text handling capabilities of MySQL aren't good enough for what you want.  A stored function is an option, but will probably be slow.  Your best bet to process the data within MySQL is to add a [user defined function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/5.7/en/adding-loadable-function.html).  If you're going to build a newer version of MySQL anyway, you could also add a [native function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/5.7/en/adding-native-function.html).

The "correct" way is to process the data outside the DB since DBs are for storage, not processing, and any heavy processing might put too much of a load on the DBMS.  Additionally, calculating the word count outside of MySQL makes it easier to change the definition of what counts as a word.  How about storing the word count in the DB and updating it when a document is changed?

Example stored function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION wordcount(str LONGTEXT)
       RETURNS INT
       DETERMINISTIC
       SQL SECURITY INVOKER
       NO SQL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE wordCnt, idx, maxIdx INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currChar, prevChar BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    SET maxIdx=char_length(str);
    SET idx = 1;
    WHILE idx <= maxIdx DO
        SET currChar=SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE '[[:alnum:]]';
        IF NOT prevChar AND currChar THEN
            SET wordCnt=wordCnt+1;
        END IF;
        SET prevChar=currChar;
        SET idx=idx+1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN wordCnt;
  END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your solution with the function is great and I love it. It just count for me words with ' (like haven't as 2). I did posted update to your function.

Answer (score 8):

This is quite a bit faster, though just slightly less accurate. I found it 4% light on the count, which is OK for "estimate" scenarios.

```
SELECT
    ROUND (   
        (
            CHAR_LENGTH(content) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE (content, " ", "")) 
        ) 
        / CHAR_LENGTH(" ")        
    ) AS count    
FROM documents
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for some similar cases (MySQL):

SELECT *,
(CHAR_LENGTH(student)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(student,' ','')))+1 as 'count'
FROM documents;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `word_count()` UDF from https://github.com/spachev/mysql_udf_bundle. I ported the logic from the accepted answer with a difference that my code only supports latin1 charset. The logic would need to be reworked to support other charsets. Also, both implementations always consider a non-alphanumeric character to be a delimiter, which may not always desirable - for example "teacher's book" is considered to be three words by both implementations.

The UDF version is, of course, significantly faster. For a quick test I tried both on a dataset from Project Guttenberg consisting of 9751 records totaling about 3 GB. The UDF did all of them in 18 seconds, while the stored function took 63 seconds to process just 30 records (which UDF does in 0.05 seconds). So the UDF is roughly 1000 times faster in this case.

UDF will beat any other method in speed that does not involve modifying MySQL source code. This is because it has access to the string bytes in memory and can operate directly on bytes without them having to be moved around. It is also compiled into machine code and runs directly on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried to use the function defined above and it was great, except one scenario.

In English you have strong use of ' as part of the word. The function above, at least to me, counted "haven't" as 2.

So here is my little correction:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION wordcount(str TEXT)
            RETURNS INT
            DETERMINISTIC
            SQL SECURITY INVOKER
            NO SQL
       BEGIN
         DECLARE wordCnt, idx, maxIdx INT DEFAULT 0;
         DECLARE currChar, prevChar BOOL DEFAULT 0;
         SET maxIdx=CHAR_LENGTH(str);
         WHILE idx < maxIdx DO
             SET currChar=SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE '[[:alnum:]]' OR SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE "'";
             IF NOT prevChar AND currChar THEN
                 SET wordCnt=wordCnt+1;
             END IF;
             SET prevChar=currChar;
             SET idx=idx+1;
         END WHILE;
         RETURN wordCnt;
       END
     $$
```