# How to find how many keywords appear in a text and sort by it using mysql?

Tags: mysql

For example, say the keywords are "Tokyo restaurant" and I have PlaceDescription column from Place table where its PlaceID=1's PlaceDescription is "XXXXX is a beautiful Tokyo restaurant." and PlaceID=2's PlaceDescription is "YYYYY is a popular Indian restaurant." and PlaceID=3's 
PlaceDescription is "ZZZZZ is a fast food restaurant at Tokyo." and PlaceID=4's PlaceDescription is "AAAAA is a successful restaurant located in Tokyo. It was a restaurant first built in year 2000."

What I want it to return is like

PlaceID    Count

1          2

2          1

3          2

4          2

I tried visiting topics at links such as [MySql: Count amount of times the words occur in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649711/mysql-count-amount-of-times-the-words-occur-in-a-column) but they don't answer my question.

SELECT PlaceID, COUNT(*) FROM Place WHERE PlaceDescription LIKE '%tokyo%' or PlaceDescription LIKE '%restaurant%';

Comment: For your fourth sentence, `Tokyo` appears only once, while `restaurant` appears twice.  Why is the total count 2 for searching on `Tokyo restaurant`?

Comment: Well the 'restaurant' keyword is already counted so any subsequent 'restaurant' word is disregarded. I'm saying the maximum value of COUNT is 2 and its corresponding minimum value is 0 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try summing your current `LIKE` expressions.  I recommend using `REGEXP` instead though:

```
SELECT
    PlaceID,
    (PlaceDescription REGEXP '[[:<:]]tokyo[[:>:]]') +
    (PlaceDescription REGEXP '[[:<:]]restaurant[[:>:]]') AS Count
FROM Place
WHERE
    PlaceDescription REGEXP '[[:<:]]tokyo|restaurant[[:>:]]';
```

Note that I am doing a regex search for `\btokyo\b` or `\brestaurant\b`, meaning that `REGEXP` would only find those exact words, surrounded by word boundaries on both sides.  Also note that `REGEXP` is not case sensitive, so both `tokyo` and `Tokyo` would be picked up and counted.

Comment: I'm sorry this code fetches all rows even those without any of 'tokyo' or 'restaurant' keywords in it.

Comment: @PeterKim Didn't know you only wanted to see matching rows.  Check the updated answer.