# Count words in column with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

```
id | words                            | other
1  | lorem ipsum                      | dsf
2  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text | sads
3  | simply dummy text                | sdf
4  | Lorem Ipsum  text                | sdfsdf
5  | simply dummy Lorem               | asddasd
```

I do SELECT * FROM words .
How can i count how many words is in this answer of query? In this example should be 17.
I use PHP and Doctrine.

Comment: If you retrieve the data to PHP from the resultset, then use PHP's str_word_count() function; if you want to do the wordcount in MySQL Itself, look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field

Comment: thanks, please add new answer:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT LENGTH(words) - LENGTH(REPLACE(words, ' ', '')) + 1 AS words_count
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Not a good solution - it works only with clean data, too many problems if there are multiple spaces between words, or leading/trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( LENGTH(words) - LENGTH(REPLACE(words, ' ', ''))+1)
FROM table
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: This query appears to make a few assumptions that don't fit the question's data provided. For example that every single space character encountered should indicate a word (note the row where `id` = 4)