# mysql count word in sql syntax

Tags: mysql

Lets have a simple query:

```
SELECT myfield
FROM   mytable
WHERE  criteria
```

The above query gives us 10 rows of results for example. The field `myField` is a text field.

My question is this: is it possible to alter the above query and get the total word count of the `myField` field?

**Edited:** By total word count I mean the total word count of all selected fields in query, in all rows

**Example**

```
+------------------------------+-------+
| sentence                     | Words |
+------------------------------+-------+
| Hello World                  |     2 |
| Hello World                  |     2 |
| Mary had a little lamb       |     5 |
| Her fleece was white as snow |     6 |
| Everywhere that mary went    |     4 |
| Umm, sheep followed her      |     4 |
+------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: The question is very confusing. Please provide us with a small data example and the expected result.

Comment: So far - 3 different interpretations. I rest my case.

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius why is it confusing? I ask for a way to get total word count of a column. Where is the confusion?

Comment: @andrew Could you please elaborate your question to remove the confusion..? What actually you want the total no of words in each cell of myfield or the total no of cells under myfeild fulfilling the criteria.?

Comment: @andrew Please take a look at the accepted answer. Then compare the visual example, which is really easily understandable to the poorly worded sentence in the question (no offense). Also, due to the fact my comment got thumbed up several times, I would say it wasn't me who thought this way. Always try to add an example when possible to get rid of any potential misinterpretations. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the excellent function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field) by @otis in your query:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------------------------------+
| id | sentence                     |
+----+------------------------------+
|  0 | Hello World                  |
|  1 | Hello World                  |
|  2 | Mary had a little lamb       |
|  3 | Her fleece was white as snow |
|  4 | Everywhere that mary went    |
|  5 | Umm, sheep followed her      |
+----+------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT sentence, wordcount(sentence) as "Words" from test;
+------------------------------+-------+
| sentence                     | Words |
+------------------------------+-------+
| Hello World                  |     2 |
| Hello World                  |     2 |
| Mary had a little lamb       |     5 |
| Her fleece was white as snow |     6 |
| Everywhere that mary went    |     4 |
| Umm, sheep followed her      |     4 |
+------------------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

To make the function work, you need to execute the declaration of the function in MySQL. It is just like executing any other query:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION wordcount(str TEXT)
            RETURNS INT
            DETERMINISTIC
            SQL SECURITY INVOKER
            NO SQL
       BEGIN
         DECLARE wordCnt, idx, maxIdx INT DEFAULT 0;
         DECLARE currChar, prevChar BOOL DEFAULT 0;
         SET maxIdx=char_length(str);
         WHILE idx < maxIdx DO
             SET currChar=SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE '[[:alnum:]]';
             IF NOT prevChar AND currChar THEN
                 SET wordCnt=wordCnt+1;
             END IF;
             SET prevChar=currChar;
             SET idx=idx+1;
         END WHILE;
         RETURN wordCnt;
       END
     $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field

Comment: Yes, but perhaps OP doesn't know how to apply the function to their query.

Comment: Given that you have edit privileges, maybe you could've edited that answer to provide a usage example then linked to it in a comment. Maybe.

Comment: Do you mean other than the example posted?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid There was no example in the question itself. There was a query which did not help at all, because this could have been interpreted in at least 2 ways. Since you can edit everything what is valuable in the question, I suggest you moving your own example to the question. Otherwise, your answer could be a good wiki for all of us and we appreciate that, but it does not answer the question, because the question is poorly worded.

Comment: cant this function be made more efficient? running a regex against every character to see if its NOT an alnum? i tried this on a relatively small table, and it locked the database for a long time until the process was killed. This only works for tiny datasets and should never be used in production.