# Calculate occurences of phrase in Text Field Django

Tags: mysql, django

How can I filter my model `MyModel` on the basis of the number of occurences of a certain phrase in a text field in `MyModel`

I guess it can't be done with django orm, perhaps an SQL query can help?

Something like:

```
MyModal.objects.extra(count="SQL query that finds occurence count of a certain phrase in certain model field")
```

A complete raw query is fine too.

Comment: I guess what you really need is the query, and you can find that in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field)

Comment: thanks @BurhanKhalid, but the link you gave has suggested to process data outside db which is something i don't want to do.

Comment: You write the function in MySQL directly. Its not external. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156970/mysql-count-word-in-sql-syntax/12157152#12157152) for an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
set @str='a b a c';
select length(@str)-length(replace(@str,'a','')) as 'number of occuarence'
```