# Selecting multiple substrings from a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a field that is a `longtext` in MySQL. I'm looking for any instances of 'media' that could be in it, +/- ~10 characters of context. There are usually multiple instances in a single rows' field, so I need to see the context. How can I write a query to do this? I can't even think of where to start.

So what I'm looking at is this:

```sql
SELECT field_data_body FROM table WHERE field_data_body LIKE '%media%';
```

```
+----------------------------------+
| field_data_body                  |
+----------------------------------+
| ... ode__media_or ... e immediat | 
+----------------------------------+
```

The field is actually a long string, and I just parsed the actual test value to show the substrings that would match the WHERE clause.

What I actually want to see is *all* instances of the string `media`, which in the example above is two, but in other fields could be more. `SUBSTR` only shows the first instance of `media`.

Comment: I guess  you need `WHERE LENGTH(mycolumn) >10` ?

Comment: can you give an example? your question is unclear to me

Comment: Are you using another language to process this data?  I'm not sure SQL is the best solution for looping through the string like this.

Comment: I could use another language (PHP really) but it would be more convenient to have a query.

Comment: do you want to search for something (e.g. media) and then return the searched expression +- 10 characters (or as much as possible if at start/end) for each match concatenated?

Comment: I don't care about concatenation, but I want to see each instance of the matched string in the field.

Comment: Ok, so this is a space delimited string and the medias have names like abc_media_whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can create a user define function for this like wordcount. You can get help from this UDF.

[mysql count word in sql syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156970/mysql-count-word-in-sql-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

[`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) of your own. Inside the function you can use the [`WHILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html) statement and general string functions such as [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

Here is an example to get you started:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION substring_list(
    haystack TEXT,
    needle VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE needle_len INT DEFAULT CHAR_LENGTH(needle);
    DECLARE output_str TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE needle_pos INT DEFAULT LOCATE(needle, haystack);
    WHILE needle_pos > 0 DO
        SET output_str = CONCAT(output_str, SUBSTRING(haystack, GREATEST(needle_pos - 10, 1), LEAST(needle_pos - 1, 10) + needle_len + 10), '\n');
        SET needle_pos = LOCATE(needle, haystack, needle_pos + needle_len);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN output_str;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here are some tests. For each match, the term ("media") and up to 10 characters on either side are returned, all concatenated in a single string:

```sql
SELECT substring_list('1234567890media12345678immediate34567890media1234567890', 'media');
```

```
+---------------------------+
| 1234567890media12345678im |
| 12345678immediate34567890 |
| te34567890media1234567890 |
+---------------------------+
```

```sql
SELECT substring_list('0media12345678immediate34567890media1', 'media');
```

```
+---------------------------+
| 0media12345678im          |
| 12345678immediate34567890 |
| te34567890media1          |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Great approach, this is a gem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using PHP that will return each row and each result plus the surrounding characters in a multidimensional array.

```
$value = "media";
$surroundingChars = 5;
$strlen = strlen($value);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT field_data_body FROM table WHERE field_data_body LIKE ?";
$stmt->execute([ '%'.$value.'%' ]);
$result = 0;
while ($body = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    $start = 0;
    while (($pos = stripos($body, $value, $start)) !== FALSE) {
         $return[$result][] = substr($body, $pos - $surroundingChars, $strlen + ($surroundingChars * 2));
         // Adjust next start 
         $start = $pos + $strlen;
    }
    $result++;
}
```

You could always change the `$return[$result][]` line, but to echo all rows in the format you wanted, you could do this:

```
foreach($return as $row) {
    echo implode('..', $row);
}
```

As you stated in the comments, you'd rather a query, but if you change your mind, here is a solution matching your PHP requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I can do this in PHP, I don't want to accept this answer because I was looking for a mysql query. But if no one pipes up with one after a while I will accept it.