SQL Query - How to select rows that have 2 words in name column?
What is the most efficient and elegant SQL query looking for a string containing the 3 words?
Example :
Name
Rahul Mano Soo
Mohit Kumar
Vinay Kumar Manocha
Vinay Manoch
Vinay
Vinay Manocha Sood

From this column, I want to fetch only those rows that has 3 words.
Output should be:
Name
Rahul Mano Soo
Vinay Kumar Manocha
Vinay Manocha Sood


Add a 4 word row to your sample data. (And, perhaps, adjust the expected result.)

WHERE Name LIKE '% % %' AND Name NOT LIKE '% % % %'. The first pattern matches at least 3 words, the second pattern matches at least 4 words. Together they match exactly 3 words.

Note that it isn't really possible to do this efficiently. This type of query can't be optimized with an index.

This question has been asked and answered many times before, for example on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156970/mysql-count-word-in-sql-syntax or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field

My apologies Jonas but the answer is not at all helpful. Thatz why I asked the question in this group. Anyways, Barmar output helped me with my query. Thank you Jonas. :-)
