# search word count query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, word-count

I have below table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product`
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'Samsung', "this is samsung product description from samsung"),
(2, 'Mobile', "Samsung galaxy note2 from samsung store"),
(3, 'Smartphone', "Samsung");
```

now i want to query on `product` table that produce result as below.

```
ID   Name       WordCount
1   Samsung        3
2   Mobile         2
3   Smartphone     1
```

how can i count this word occurrence in `MySQL` select query.

**EDIT**

Sorry for not clearing my point.

But here it is.

I want to `search` word `Samsung` from all the rows and count its occurrence not only from name but from also description too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field

Comment: I think `Jacob Tomlinson`'s reference is right. It might not be an exact duplicate but it points you in the right direction. `The "correct" way is to process the data outside the DB since DBs are for storage, not processing,...`

Comment: @Ejay Thanx for help but i have got it..i have posted answer so other can solve same issue..

Comment: @JacobTomlinson thanx for being first to response and help me//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few hours of googlling and debugging finally i have got it solved.

I have used combination of char_length and replace to achieve this task.

What i end up with is as below.

```
select  *,(
    (char_length(name) - char_length(replace(name,'sam',''))) +
    (char_length(description) - char_length(replace(description,'sam','')))
) / char_length('sam') as SearchCount
from
    product
order by
    SearchCount desc
```

above query is **CASE SENSITIVE** but do not worry i have also solved it with **CASE-INSESITIVE** see below query.

```
select  *,
(
    (char_length(name) - char_length(replace(LOWER(name),LOWER('Sam'),''))) +
    (char_length(description) - 
    char_length(replace(LOWER(description),LOWER('Sam'),'')))
) / char_length('sam') as SearchCount
from
    product
order by
    SearchCount desc
```

after having this query all we need to do is add `WHERE` clause to make it work.

Hope this will help other People too.

**Thanks for help (All the people who answered and deleted and comment.)**