# SQL Query Counting Instances of a Word in a Record

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-matching

I want to find out how many times a word occurs in a single row.

For Example:
I have table sentences and it has only one column call words which is a string data type. The table has only one row with the value "The mans interest in raising the flag flagged."

I want to get the number of times 'the' occurs which is 2
And if I want to get the number of times 'flag' appears it would be 2

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL to determine word count stats of a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no internal mysql function counting occurences of a substring in a string, but you can compare length of a string to a string with your word replaced by empty strings, as `REPLACE()` works for all occurences.

```
SELECT
 (CHAR_LENGTH(sentence)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(sentence),'the','')))/CHAR_LENGTH('the')
 AS occurences
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Strangely similar to the one from provided by `Babblo` link.

Comment: How would you replace sentence with the data from the columns?

Comment: Figured out how to replace sentence with the data from column. Thanks.