# SQL count number of words in field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, postgresql

I'd like to make an SQL query where the condition is that column1 contains three or more words. Is there something to do that?

Comment: Yes, you should first decide on the database you are using and tag your question appropriately.  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Postgres?  Something else.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: maybe use a regular expression - then count the matches

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SQL to determine word count stats of a text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field)

Comment: You will not find a single SQL statement which does this reliably on **all** mentioned DBMS

Answer (score 32):

maybe try counting spaces ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE (LENGTH(column1) - LENGTH(replace(column1, ' ', ''))) > 1
```

and assume words is number of spaces + 1

Comment: Wont handle multiple spaces between words

Comment: @ErstwhileIII . . . I don't think that limitation is really worth a downvote, given that the OP doesn't specify what the delimiters are.  One space is a reasonable assumption (although the answers could make that explicit).

Comment: `len()` is a microsoft invention, it's not portable

Comment: Well ... only if one does not care about accuracy

Comment: It may not produce 100% accurate results, but is there any better solution?  I upvoted.  My main gripe about this approach is it will be very slow for anything but very small tables.

Comment: it has a syntax issue, one more bracket ) is required after )).

Answer (score 5):

If you want a condition that a column contains three or more words *and* you want it to work in a bunch of databases *and* we assume that words are separated by single spaces, then you can use `like`:

```
where column1 like '% % %'
```

Comment: that would match a column containing only two spaces `where column1 like '%_ %_ %_'` is only slightly better.

Comment: @Jasen . . . Read the answer.  The assumption is clearly stated that words are separated by a single space.  A string consisting only of spaces would not meet that condition.

Comment: I must admit that your answer is the only one that will execute in all three databases.

Answer (score 5):

I think David nailed it above. However, as a more complete answer:

```
LENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(column1,'  ', ' ')))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(column1, '  ', ' '))), ' ', '')) + 1 AS number_of_words
```

This will remove double spaces, as well as leading and trailing spaces in your string.

Of course, you may go further by adding replacements for more than 2 spaces in a row...

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres you can use `regexp_split_to_array()` for this:

```
select *
from the_table
where array_length(regexp_split_to_array(the_column, '\s+'), 1) >= 3;
```

This will split the contents of the column `the_column` into array elements. One ore more whitespace are used as the delimiter. It won't respect "quoted" spaces though. The value `'one "two three" four'` will be counted as four words.

Comment: Can you explain to me in detail what that "1" flag at the end of regexp_split_to_array does? I can't find the documentation on it

Comment: @Tom: that's a parameter for `array_length()` not for `regexp_split_to_array()`

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this, is to NOT do this.

Instead, you should use the application layer to count the words during INSERT and save the word count into its own column.

While I like, and upvoted, some of the answers here, all of them will be very slow and not 100% accurate.

I know people want a simple answer to SELECT the word count, but it just is NOT POSSIBLE with accuracy and speed.

If you want it to be 100% accurate, and very fast, then use this solution.

Steps to solve:

1. Add a column to your table and index it: `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN wordcount INT UNSIGNED NULL, ADD INDEX idxtablename_count (wordcount ASC);`.
2. Before doing your INSERT, count the number of words using your application.  For example in PHP: `$count = str_word_count($somevalue);`
3. During the INSERT, include the value of `$count` for the column `wordcount` like `insert into tablename (col1, col2, col3, wordcount) values (val1, val2, val3, $count);`

Then your select statement becomes super easy, clean, uber-fast, and 100% accurate.

`select * from tablename where wordcount >= 3;`

Also remember when you are updating any rows that you will need to recount the words for that column.

Comment: This is the best answer because it is the only one that is 100% accurate and does not do a full table scan (and so it is fast, unlike the other solutions)

Comment: This is not the best answer because it does not answer the question.

Comment: @KenJohnson "I'd like to make an SQL query where the condition is that column1 contains three or more words. Is there something to do that?" was the question and `select * from tablename where wordcount >= 3;` is my answer, if you want to be semantically accurate.  OP asked for a query.  OP got a query.

Comment: @KenJohnson, I'm a little late here, but sometimes a question can be answered by asking a different question and answering that one. In my experience, some hard problems become easy when adding a layer of abstraction or solving the problem at a different stage in the code's lifecycle.

Comment: @JaredMenard I totally agree with that sentiment, and i believe that this answer has a place in this thread. I merely contest the statement that this is the "best answer" since it answers it in a roundabout way, with contrived constraints (albeit constraints that others may identify with).

Comment: @KenJohnson Then "best" without further specification is a subjective term.

Answer (score 1):

For "n" or more words

```
select *
from table
where (length(column)- length(replace(column, " ", "")) + 1) >= n
```

PS: This would not work if words have multiple spaces between them.

Answer (score 1):

With  ClickHouse DB You can use splitByWhitespace() function.

Refer : https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/splitting-merging-functions#splitbywhitespaces

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an example of query (relevant to the question) using this function in the answer itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32405542)

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers seem to take multiple spaces into account. For example, a lot of people use two spaces between sentences; these space-counters would count an extra word per sentence. `"Also, scenarios such as spaces around a hyphen - like that. "`

For my purposes, this was **far** more accurate:

```sql
SELECT 
  LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(myText, '[ \n\t\|\-]{1,}',' ')) - 
  LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(myText, '[ \n\t\|\-]{1,}', '')) wordCount FROM myTable;
```

It counts any sets of **1 *or more* consecutive** characters from any of: [`space`, `linefeed`, `tab`, `pipe`, or `hyphen`] and counts it as one word.

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
SUM(LENGTH(a) - LENGTH(REPLACE(a, ' ', '')) + 1)
```

Where `a` is the string column. It will count the number of spaces, which is 1 less than the number of words.

Comment: won't handle multiple spaces between "words"

Comment: Microsoft's server doesn't do Length(),

Comment: You shouldn't have SUM in there.

Answer (score -2):

To handle multiple spaces too, use the method shown here

```
Declare @s varchar(100)
set @s='  See      how many                        words this      has  '
set @s=ltrim(rtrim(@s))

while charindex('  ',@s)&gt;0
Begin
    set @s=replace(@s,'  ',' ')
end

select len(@s)-len(replace(@s,' ',''))+1 as word_count
```

https://exploresql.com/2018/07/31/how-to-count-number-of-words-in-a-sentence/