# MySQL - word frequency count on long textual field

Tags: mysql, sql, word-count

I have a `MySQL` table, where one of the fields contains a textual description (~5-200 words).

For example `Reviews`:

```
Rev_id    Place_id    Stars    Category    Text
1         12           3        Food       Nice food but a bad dirty place.
2         31           4        Sport      Not bad, they have everything.
3         55           1        Bar        Poor place,bad audience.
```

I'd like to make some word count analysis, such as general word frequency count (how many times each of the words has appeared) or top-K words per Category.

In the example:

```
word    count
bad     3
place   2
...
```

Is there a way to do it solely in `MySQL` without involving programming languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL to determine word count stats of a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276/using-sql-to-determine-word-count-stats-of-a-text-field)

Comment: It's not the same - I'm not interested in the number of words per text, but in the general number of times each word has appeared.

Comment: @MohaMad can you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My logic for this question is: extract all words and count them!

So, create a table like your stored data:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbltest` (
  `Rev_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `place_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stars` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Rev_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`Rev_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And creating a table for words:

```
CREATE TABLE `counting` (
  `word` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `counts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`word`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word_UNIQUE` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, create the [MySQL Stored Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) for splitting sentences and counting words:

```
drop procedure if exists sentence_words;
delimiter #
create procedure sentence_words(IN Cat VARCHAR(45))

begin

declare w_max int unsigned default 1;
declare w_counter int unsigned default 0;
declare done int unsigned default 0;

declare sentence varchar(255) default null;
declare cur cursor for select `text` from `tbltest` where `Category` = Cat;
declare continue handler for not found set done=1;
set done=0;
open cur;
    myloop: loop
        fetch cur into sentence;
        if done = 1 then leave myloop; end if;
        -- refine sentence!
        set sentence = replace(replace(replace(replace(
                sentence
        ,'.',' '),'!',' '),',',' '),';',' ');
        set sentence = replace(trim(sentence),'  ',' ');
        set w_max = length(sentence)-length(replace(sentence,' ',''))+1;
        start transaction;
        while w_counter < w_max do
            insert into `counting`(counts,word) values
                (1, substring_index( substring_index(
                    sentence,' ',w_counter+1) ,' ',-1)
                )
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counts=counts+1;
            set w_counter=w_counter+1;
        end while;
        commit;
    end loop;
    close cur;
end #
delimiter ;
```

Finally, you can call the procedure and find words and counts in `counting` table. If you need each category word counts separated, remember to `truncate` or backup `counting` table before calling procedure for each Category.

```
truncate `counting`;
call sentence_words('Bar');
select * from `counting` order by counts desc; -- ? where length(word)>2
-- words | counts --
'audience', '1'
'bad', '1'
'place', '1'
'Poor', '1'
```